# how to enumerate the response set from FQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

```
var response = _facebookAPI.Fql.Query(String.Format("SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid={0}", myevent));
```

I would like to convert response to

`List<long> uids`

Comment: Could you post the XML response string you receive when you perform this query?

Comment: What is the return type of the call to Fql.Query(...);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the string returned is an XMLDocument:

```
var response = _facebookAPI.Fql.Query(String.Format("SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid={0}", myevent));
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.LoadXml(response); 
XmlNodeList uids = doc.GetElementsByTagName("uid"); 

var uids = new List<long>();
foreach (XmlNode node in uids)
{
      long id;
      if (long.TryParse(node.InnerText, out id))
      {
           uids.Add(id);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I believe Tom mentioned in an earlier comment (now deleted) that the response is an XML string.